# Rails, LDAP & RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, rspec-rails, webmock

I have a custom LDAP configuration for my Rails API application.  Are there any good examples out there for mocking the configuration with a combination of RSpec and Webmock?

I want to make sure I have proper code coverage and unfortunately things I have found like [fakeldap](https://github.com/per-garden/fakeldap) are not compatible with my setup (Rails 5.0.4 with Ruby 2.4.1).